# SQL Server set based processing for orders and details

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have been trying to get acclimated to set based processing with SQL Server.  Below is a simplified version of cursor processing for this task.  It involves creating an order from items in a shopping cart.  The order is created, line items are added to the order details table, the total is accumulated and eventually updated on the order table.  Can anyone suggest how to do this with a set based approach instead of a cursor?

One other question is that in most cases the cursor will process at most 10 or 12 line items at a time.  Is that enough of a reason to not have to consider the set based approach?

```
declare getCart2 cursor for
select  MemberID,ProductID,Quantity,Price
from    Carts
where   MemberID = @MemberID

open getCart2
fetch next from getCart2 into @MemberID,@ProductID,@Quantity,@Price
Insert into Orders 
(MemberID,TotalAmount0
Values
(@MemberID, 0.00) 
set @OrderID = @@Identity

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 Begin
    Insert into OrderDetails
    (OrderID,ProductID,Quantity)
    Values
    (@OderID,@ProductID,@Quantity)
    set @TotalAmout = @TotalAmount + (@Quantity * @Price)

    set @PrevMemberID = @MemberID
    fetch next from getCart2 into @MemberID,@ProductID,@Quantity,@Price
End

close getCart2
deallocate getCart2

Update Orders 
Set TotalAmount = @TotalAmount
Where OrderID = @OrderID
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes an approach:

In this case I am creating a temporary table variable that will store the order id's on it.

Then, it performs the insertions on the Order table and after that, in the OrderDetails.

Finally, it computes the TotalAmount and updates on the Orders table.

Although you don't have it in your code (and in mine as well), but I recommend you to use this code inside a transaction.

Hope it helps you improve your performance.

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Carts', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[Carts];
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Orders', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[Orders];
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.OrderDetails', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails];
GO

-- Creates the tables like you have
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Carts] (MemberID INT, ProductID INT, Quantity INT, Price DECIMAL(10, 2));
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (OrderID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), MemberID INT, TotalAmount DECIMAL(10, 2));
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetails] (OrderID INT, ProductID INT, Quantity INT);

-- Inserts dummy data
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Carts] VALUES (1001, 80, 5, 25.00);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Carts] VALUES (1002, 120, 2, 12.90);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Carts] VALUES (1010, 70, 3, 12.00)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Carts] VALUES (1034, 176, 5, 45.00);

-- Temporary table that stores the inserted Order ID's
DECLARE @OrdersToProcess TABLE (OrderID INT, MemberID INT);

-- Inserts all Orders
INSERT INTO Orders (MemberID, TotalAmount)
    OUTPUT inserted.OrderID, inserted.MemberID INTO @OrdersToProcess
    SELECT MemberID, 0
    FROM [dbo].[Carts]

-- Inserts order details
INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity)
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, Quantity
    FROM [dbo].[Carts] C
    INNER JOIN @OrdersToProcess O ON C.MemberID = O.MemberID;

-- Updates order totals
UPDATE [dbo].[Orders]
SET TotalAmount = T.Total FROM
(
SELECT OrderID, SUM(Quantity * Price) AS [Total]
    FROM [dbo].[Carts] C
    INNER JOIN @OrdersToProcess O ON C.MemberID = O.MemberID
    GROUP BY OrderID
) T
WHERE [dbo].[Orders].OrderID = T.OrderID

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Orders];
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[OrderDetails];
```

#### Results:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks, Pedro.  This is the direction I needed.  It is more complicated than my example and yes, it is all wrapped inside a transaction.  One last note is that we probably need to drop the OrdersToBeProcessed temp table at the end.!  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, welcome. You don't need to drop the OrdersToProcess variable, since it's a variable. It's different from a temporary table #OrdersToProcess.Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, this store procedure should be called when a particular member presses the check-out button, so it should create a single order with all the items in the cart of that member.

You can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (MemberID, TotalAmount)
VALUES (@MemberID, 0)

SET @OrderID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity)
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, Quantity
FROM [dbo].[Carts] C
WHERE C.MemberID=@MemberID

UPDATE dbo.Orders SET TotalAmount=(
    SELECT SUM(c.Quantity*c.Price)
    FROM dbo.Carts c
    WHERE c.MemberID=@MemberID
) WHERE OrderID=@OrderID
```

It's true that this reads the `Carts` table twice, but with a proper index (on the `MemberID` column) that should be fast enough.

Comment: Wow!  This is good too.  Yes, the carts table is indexed on the MemberID...thanks!